# how do I get webcam to work on my lg x120 in lubuntu 13.04?

Tags: lubuntu, webcam, lg

first time noob so dont be hard on me :)

I recently installed Lubuntu 13.04 on an old LG x120 netbook, everything works fine except the webcam.

tested it in skype, google hangouts and cheese. the first two indicate that there is no camera connected and the third just show black square.

I've googled the problem for a few hours and tried various solutions without success...

at first I found [this page](http://www.linlap.com/lg_x120-g)- that states that the lg x120 webcam "Works perfectly in skype/cheese/ffmpeg - uses uvcvideo driver".

and then I tried unsuccessfully to find a way to install/activate this "uvcvideo" driver.

and then I came across [this page](http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=36141) - states that after installing Lubuntu on the x120 "Almost everything works just fine right after the installation (webcam, wifi, touchpad, 3g adaptor...)"

Am I doing something wrong?

btw, the camera worked just fine on windows 7 with the proper driver installed...

lsusb shows :

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 17ef:6019 Lenovo 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 18e8:6252 Qcom 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

have no idea what is means... :(

Comment: Not that I don't believe you (I do), but how do you know the webcam doesn't work? The question lacks any info on how you tested it, and what was the result. The output of `lsusb` would also have been nice.

Comment: added lsusb results, and I know it doesn't work because I tested it in skype, google hangouts and cheese. the first two indicate that there is no camera connected and the third just show black square.

Comment: Enter Synaptic Package Manager and make sure that your system has the following files installed: libv4l-0 and libwebcam0

Comment: libv4l-0 - was installed. libwebcam0 - was not, installed it, restarted pc - nothing... :(

Comment: my last 2 cents, install GUVCVIEW from Synaptic Package Manager, run it and see if your webcam gets output (guvcvideo), if none, go to the "video & files" tab of the GUVCViewer (already open) and on the "Device" select your webcam and a coupple of lines below in "Camera Output" start playing with the different output modes there are (mine worked with YUYV, after messing with them for a bit) and see if some output is shown.

Comment: guvcview wont start : (translated from hebrew:) "cannot open device. please make sure that the camera is connected and the proper driver is installed."

Comment: I am not sure the webcam is shown in the output of lsusb. The `17ef:6019 Lenovo` appears to be a mouse, and I could not find what's `18e8:6252 Qcom`. Can you add the outputs of `dmesg | grep video`, and `ls /dev/v4l/*` to the question. Also check if the driver is loaded: `lsmod | grep uvcvideo`, and if not, try loading it with `sudo modprobe uvcvideo`.

Comment: dmesg | grep video : [    0.249166] pci 0000:00:02.0: Boot video device.   
ls /dev/v4l/* : ls: cannot access /dev/v4l/*: No such file or directory. 
lsmod | grep uvcvideo : does nothing (just drop to next line).  sudo modprobe uvcvideo : the same.

Comment: Hm..., looks like no webcam is detected. Could it be broken? How much time has it been, since it worked in Windows 7?